# Sankey diagram, alluvial, ggalluvial in R – Three data blocks: Baseline-Flow (many time points)-Outcome

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

We would like to present the change in muscle mass due to the exercise of different age group and the final performance/outcome at the competition at the end of the study.
We have several time points at which the muscle mass was measured. In this example I only show three time points, however, the study compromises 12 time points.
To present the change in muscle mass and deviation from the average I was able to use `geom_flow()`. However, it becomes very tricky to add the age groups on the left of the chart as well as the performance on the right side. These data are located in different variables.
Please help us to find a great way to present the data. Thanks.

Data Structure:
ID  Age_at_start    Month   Deviation_muscle    Performance
1        36                3            59                           Outstanding
1            36               6          104                          Outstanding
1            36                 9            200                          Outstanding
2            29                 3            -40                           average
2         29                 6         -109                          average
2            29              9           -30                          average
3          22               3           310                           above average

[image: Example how the chart should look like]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalluvial)

df.san$age<-factor(df.san$age)
df.san$age<-factor(df.san$age, levels=c(1,2,3,4), labels=c("20 to 24 years","25 to 29 years","30 to 34 years","35 to 39 years"))
df.san$dev_group <-factor(df.san$dev_group,levels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),labels=c("≥250g","≥150 to <250g","≥50 to <150g","> -50 to <50g","> -150 to ≤ -50","> -250 to ≤ -150", "≤ -250g"))
df.san$month <- factor(df.san$month,labels=c("1mo","2mo","3mo"))
df.san$perform<-factor(df.san$perform,levels=c(1,2,3,4),labels=c("outstanding "," above average "," average "," below average"))
ggplot(df.san,aes(x = month,stratum = dev_group, alluvium = ID, fill = dev_group,label = dev_group)) +
scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "rightleft", color = "darkgray") +
geom_stratum() +
theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
ggtitle("Effect of Exercice on Muscle Growth on Performance in 4 Different Age Groups ")
```

Data for df.san:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L), age = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L), month = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L), dev_muscle = c(-109.3, -236.2, -275.4, -44.5, -202.6, -436, 3, -115.8, -136.2, -142.1, -429, -561.4, -49, -248.8, -232.6, -15.9, -171.5, -391.6, -5.8, -21.7, -104.1, 12.6, -33.4, -25.4, -57.3, -50.7, -103.6, -124, -221.4, -457.2, 22.1, -126.9, -79.5, -76.8, -113.2, -129.7, -86.1, -126, -82.9, -10.8, -2.8, 88.3, 41.6, 0.2, 184.7), perform = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L), dev_group = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -45L))
```

Comment: Please dput a sample of your data.

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data and the code you're working on so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: I added a sample data set, I hope that it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Niels , welcome to SO! You've correctly added your data, but it's not a good option to give a link with them; we do not know the link, if it's safe or not: remember, we are completely strangers. You'll have bigger chances to have a good answer if you post the result of the code `dput(your_dataset)`, I suppose something like `dput(df.san)` or, if you do not want share your data, you can create some fake data, or `dput(head(df.san,20))` to put only 20 rows. Also, your code seems not working, and you've not put the external packages in (`ggplot2`, `ggalliuvial`).

Comment: @s_t , thanks for your suggestion, I removed the link and added the data. I hope it is correct now, I also check the code, it should work now. Thanks